# Link on pdf triggers .sh/.py/.bat

Tags: links, python, shell-escape, bash, batchmode

I have been looking for a while for a solution in LaTex. My intention is to create a link inside a PDF generated with LaTex that triggers a .sh/.py/.bat by clicking in the link. Not like \write18, that triggers it at compilation.

¿Do you know if it is possible to do what I am looking for?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: well you can try something like `\href{run:batch.bat}{Run batchfile}`, but normally PDF viewer will simply not allow that and block the execution.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike! It seems to work for bat on windows, but I need to prove it later on a computer where I have administrator rights.

Comment: I do not achieve the same approach for bash on Linux. It just opens as text file. Any idea? I will try to do it with a different PDF viewer.

Comment: it depends on the pdf viewer but most do not allow it (it's a security nightmare)

Comment: much safer than finding a pdf viewer that allows a `run` action is to use a normal http(s) link to a web server that you control and attach the exectutable command to the back end server using php or whatever, that way the security sandboxing of the command happens on the server running under its permissions, rather than having a pdf where clicking on any link gives the creator of the pdf full access to your machine with your permissions.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle noted, it is a security nightmare, thus reputable PDF viewers do not allow it. Indeed, "famous name" software had his problem maybe a decade ago, which enabled malicious PDF do do things such as inspect the contents of other files on the drive, and report the values to somewhere else.